# Perl - Getting value from comma separated line

Tags: perl

I've got a perl file parser I am trying to rewrite.
This is a dynamic parser, and I need to extract a value from a comma separated line.

The line I want to get one value from looks something like this:

```
ENTRYNAME-8,44544,99955,52,156,15:16:16,15:19:16
```

(*This is the only line in the each parsed file that starts with`ENTRYNAME-`. Everything after the `-` changes for each file being parsed*)

I want the value after the second comma. (`99955` in the example above)

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
if (/ ENTRYNAME-\((.*)\,(.*)\,(.*)\)/ ) 
{
    $entry_nr = $3;
    print "entry number = $entry_nr";
    next;
}
```

Comment: Preferably use `Text::CSV`, or at least split line on separator, `split /,/`

Comment: Will these csv lines ever be quoted and have embedded ',' in the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your first capture string `.*` is greedy, so it will consume all of your string. It will then backtrack to find two commas and as a result match from the end.

Also:

- You are matching literal parentheses `\(` for some strange reason. Since you do not have any such, those will never match.
- You do not need to escape commas `\,`
- You cannot have a random space in your regex `/ ENTRY...` unless you have one in your target string
- You do not need to capture strings that you are not going to use

A simple fix is to use a stricter capture group (including the points above):

```
if (/ENTRYNAME-\d+,\d+,(\d+)/ )
```

This will capture into `$1`.

As mpapec points out in the comment, you may wish to use `Text::CSV` to parse CSV data. It will be a lot safer. If your data is simple enough, this solution will do.

Comment: Thanks! This finally made it all come together. I would have used Text::CSV, but the input data is not simple in any way.

Comment: @user2837756 You should probably only use `Text::CSV` if you have proper csv data. A regex is a viable small scale solution for a limited data set with limited variations. But you should probably add some safe guards and error reporting, in case you run into unexpected variations.

Answer (score 1):

split it into an array and address directly:

```
my @a = split /,/, $_;
print $a[2];
```

what happens here is that whatever is in $_ (typically from a `for (@allmylines) {`-loop) will be split at each occurence of `,`, placing them all into an array (`@a`) and removing the `,`. then you may address the fields in the arrays, starting with 0 for the first field. thus if you like to address the third field, use `$a[2]` to retrieve the third item.

Comment: @Brett_Schneider What if each line has quoted strings with embedded commas?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus it does not say any of that in the question, therefore i see no point in spending time contemplating it.

Comment: @Victor i have considered it and thus extended my answer towards this point.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible separate parsing from processing and validating your data.

In this case, if you have comma separated values, go ahead and separate those values.  Then worry about filtering your data.  Whether you use `Text::CSV` for parsing is a separate issue, although probably a good idea.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split ',';

    if ($cols[0] =~ /^ENTRYNAME/) {
        print $cols[2], "\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
ENTRYNAME-8,44544,99955,52,156,15:16:16,15:19:16
```

Outputs:

```
99955
```